# How do I invite my friends to my lobby in Fortnite Mobile?

Tags: ios, fortnite-battle-royale

I want to invite my friends to Fortnite Mobile, but there is no invite link to invite my friends. My device is an iPad Air 2.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you press the plus sign of where your friends would be standing?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you reverted the title edit? The title “Fortnite mobile invite help” doesn’t explain what the issue is

Comment: Those additional tags are not required. We only use platform tags when the platform has special capabilities.

Comment: The platform does have special capabilities

Comment: If we keep taking out a tag, do **not** put it back again.  We're trying to properly organize and categorize the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How inviting on mobile (iOS) is done:

1. Launch Fortnite on your mobile device.
2. Sign In with your registered account.
3. At the Lobby Screen, tap the Friend Invite Button.
4. Click the share button to send the invite link to your friends.

Now currently the only way to play with friends is using friend codes. Which I assume you have? You need to give this code to a player upon using it he will be added to your friends list.

There are also some requirements for friends to join you.

- an internet connection
- iOS 11 on iPhone 6S/SE, iPad Mini 4 , iPad Pro, iPad Air 2, iPad 2017 or later devices.

It seems you match these requirements. So I would suggest looking to see if you have any codes. As it currently states you have 0 friends (online).

[Source](https://www.dexerto.com/news/friend-invites-fortnite-mobile-now-live-send-invite/46332)